# Webforms - update UI while waiting for long running task

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, async-await

I'm using **c#/webforms** for a form. The form also relies on **UpdatePanels**.

On the final step the event launches a long running (90 secs) **HttpPost** to a third party site.

At present when the submit button is pressed, I present a modal overlay while the process takes place, then redirect the user to another page on completion.

This is okay, but it doesn't refresh the update panel during the process, so the UI doesn't reflect the true picture - it's a step behind.

I've only just moved from **Asp.Net 4.0** so not had the opportunity to investigate **async await** stuff until now.

I'm testing a new process but can't get it to work the way I want.

Here's the event that's called on the final step:

```
    protected async void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            Task<bool> post = PostApplication();

            var step = Int32.Parse(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument);

            SetStepState(step, StepState.Complete);
            upStepper.Update();

            var result = await PostApplication();

            Response.Redirect("/Result.aspx");
        }
    }


    public async Task<bool> PostApplication()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        return true;
    }
```

The task does its job properly and a result is returned in 3 seconds, followed by the redirect.

What is not happening is the UI isn't being updated during the wait.  The method **SetStepState()** updates a data-attribute on the current step, which in turn should change how the step displays, but it doesn't. I've also forced an update to the update panel immediately after changes but nothing changes.

I'm not sure whether what I'm attempting is possible so would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Webforms does not work that way. You need to update the UI with something like ajax in between PostBack's.

Comment: You're working with Web Forms. Not Windows Forms. That means it's a web application, and based on HTTP requests and responses. The entire response is going to be generated before being returned to the client and updating the UI. You're better off using AJAX, instead of using crude abstractions like UpdatePanel. But that can really be said about Web Forms in general.

Comment: @mason - the main issue I'm deliberating is how to call a method from Ajax. Sure, I know how to update the UI using jQuery but I still need to call a number of back end method that do various things.

Comment: You must check the [UpdateProgress Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821.aspx), that does 100% what you are trying to do. I suggest you to set up a modal with a "Loading Text" inside that control. **WATCH OUT FOR THE TIMEOUT!**